# Reacting when user presses ENTER

Tags: javascript, events, keycode, enter

I'm working on an application where it should be possible to run a function if the user presses **<kbd>ENTER</kbd>** regardless of where the focus is on the page (eg. in a textbox or on a button etc).

Below is the code i've experimented with, just to find out how to react when the user presses **<kbd>ENTER</kbd>**, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
var Capsule = {

init: function() {
    var button = document.getElementById("txtInput");
    button.focus();

    Capsule.events();
},

events: function() {
    function checkKeyboard(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            console.log("Pressed ENTER.");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
}

window.onload = Capsule.init;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to bind the event as well..

- `onkeydown` - if you want to capture the event right after the key has pressed down.
- `onkeypress` - if you want to capture each keystroke while holding the key pressed.
- `onkeyup` - If you want to capture the event right after lifting the key.

Since you're using `return false;` (I recommend `e.preventDefault()`, you're probably looking for `onkeydown` or `onkeypress`. The default action cannot be prevented at `onkeyup`, because the default behaviour has already occurred.

Code:

```
events: function() {
    function checkKeyboard(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            console.log("Pressed ENTER.");
            return false;
        }
    }
    window.onkeypress = checkKeyboard; //Or: document.onkeypress = ..
}
```